# How to add key with unique random value in HTTP Request defaults in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to apply load  sample request is like

> http://54.174.110.64:8080/adserver/html5/inwapads/?adFormat=preappvideo&ak=O4DCX2&version=1.0&adu=5&cb=1494853894218&output=vast&priority=1&size=[vdo_adSize]&pageURL=http://qa.vdopia.com/qa/Ruchi/ssp_preroll1.html?0.7888977&domain=vdopia.com&refURL=&category=[CATEGORY]&siteName=vdopia&displayManager=Vdopia-SPP-Web&di=[COOKIE_ID]&dif=fpcm&sex=[GENDER]&age=[AGE];ipAddress=203.122.9.130;di=abcdefghijklmn

I have single request, what I want is that same request should have unique `di` (last key in query param). Nothing else I want to change.

My test is based on unique `di` in request keeping other parameters constant.

Comment: Try to use `random variable` or `CSV data set config` element and parameterize your script for query param `di`.

Comment: random variable how to use can you please give some example I am new to jmeter

Comment: Is there any restriction on `di`, like length? Can it be numeric?

Comment: alphanumeric more than 5 char would be fine

Comment: Try like this `${__RandomString(6,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}` and check these section from the jmeter manual http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random and http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Random function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random).

Hint:

[image]

Comment: Do I need to add any listner in my test plan ?

Comment: The listeners are used to see the tested results, analysis and debugging purpose only. To see your results, you can add a listener to view results tree but remember do not use any listeners when u are actually doing your load test.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) which will generate a [GUID structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which is unique according to the underlying algorithm each time being called.

If you don't like dashes you can remove them via [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like

```
${__groovy("${__UUID}".replaceAll("-"\, ""),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter generate unique value]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get started with JMeter Functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below approach :
[image: Jmeter]

ad di=${di_random}in path of HTTP request